# What are good options for wall plate that isn’t level?

Tags: framing, shed

I have a shed I’m building. Looks like the slab had a slight dip along one side, and it wasn’t too noticeable until I bolted the wall down with anchors.

So long story short, the wall top plate has a dip in it. If I toss my 8 foot level down the length, I can definitely see light coming through. I’d say in the middle it’s maybe 1/4 inch dip.

I guess my question is, best way to fix it, or should I just leave it? What issues will this cause when framing and setting the roof?

Side note, it’s a double wall plate if that means anything. Thanks all

Comment: For a shed probably leave it, but as a dip you can shim up the low section to be level if you want, a 1/4 or 1/2 inch should not matter structurally, but might bug you looking at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert shims under the roof rafters/trusses where they contact the plate to keep them level.

Comment: I picked this solely because it won’t cause me to back track. I appreciate all the answers guys!

Answer (score 3):

- It's a shed, how perfect does it have to be? If it stands up and keeps water out, that might suit well enough. But since you're asking, probably not for you.
- Unbolt the wall, correct the slab, rebolt the wall.
- Take off the plate, trim the studs, put the plate back on.
- Unbolt the anchors in the low spots, insert shims of a rot-resistant type until level, rebolt the anchors.